# Migration of WordPress questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, wordpress-se, migration

Before wordpress.stackexchange.com/ was created, a lot of WordPress questions were asked on SO. Are these going to be migrated, or are they going to stay in SO?

> A good example is this question:
>
> [Make *ALL* Wordpress Categories use their Parent Category Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119961/make-all-wordpress-categories-use-their-parent-category-template)

Also, if a question is migrated to another site, what happens to the reputation gained from it?

Comment: I can't comment for the specific issue of Wordpress alone, but in general [take some precautions when migrating old questions to the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76702/should-we-migrate-old-questions-to-new-se-sites). You don't want to overwhelm all of their new content with a whole bunch of old, solved content. To address your final point, ["Reputation is not migrated between sites"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51085/why-is-the-reputation-from-transferred-questions-missing-from-reputation-report/64755#64755).

Comment: Ok. Do migrated questions still keep the old timestamp, or do they jump to the front of the queue? If they keep the original timestamp, I don't see why there would be a large problem.

Comment: Just to reiterate what @Grace said. They *will* appear on the front page of recent questions. Plus there's very little point migrating old content - there's a good chance you'll be creating a duplicate on the target site.

Comment: Stack Overflow and the TeX SE site went through this exact debate not too long ago. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70466/can-so-questions-on-tex-be-migrated-to-tex-sx) from after TeX SE got on its feet, and [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stack-overflow) from before TeX SE was up and running that got updated recently.

Comment: Ok well that answers my questions, thanks guys.