# Should some frozen questions link to other stack exchanges?

Tags: feature-request, community, help

I'm looking in particular at this question: [How can you program if you're blind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118984/how-can-you-program-if-youre-blind).

I get the reason the question is frozen, but it seems like the note should link to a place people could ask something related. Perhaps http://programmers.stackexchange.com in this case.

The topic of this particular question did perhaps increase my awareness of the note's abruptness, but this type of added suggestion could help inquirers of any non-stackoverflow topic find the right place for their question.

Comment: Hm, if the question was a good fit for Programmers it would have been migrated instead of closed & locked.

Comment: @Yannis: It was probably not migrated because it was [too old](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8004/should-we-migrate-old-questions). While I don't generally spend time on Programmers, I find it hard to believe that the question wouldn't have been accepted on that site if asked today.

Comment: Maybe the concern was external links 404ing after the page was moved. I don't know if that's the case, but if migrated questions were set up to have their old URLs forward, if only in cases with popular questions, that could be a good solution too.

Comment: Well, it wasn't too old when it was first asked. And it would get closed on Programmers if asked today, it's "not constructive". Of course, that says absolutely nothing at all about it's awesomeness, it's just a question that doesn't really work with the Q&A philosophy and format of Stack Exchange (this one kinda worked, but it's an exception).